# RxJava2: Nested loops - Outer loop needs to know when inner loop completed

Tags: rx-java2

I need some guidance for resolving the following requirement:

I have a method that returns `Completable` and inside it has 2 loops which the outer loop should return `complete` only when 2 loops completed iterating all items.

Here is my attempt:

```
private Completable myMethod(Snapshot snapshot, ...) {
  return Completable.create(emitter -> {
    Flowable.fromIterable(DAYS)
    .flatMapSingle(day -> Flowable.fromIterable(ISSUES)
        .filter(this::filterByDay)
        .count()
        .map(issueCount -> snapshot.setIssueCount(issueCount))
    ).subscribe(next -> {}, 
                emitter::onError,
                emitter::completed);
  });
}
```

This doesn't do what I expect it to, since the outer loop  completes before the inner! they subscribed independently.
How can I make this work so the method returns `Completable` only when both loops completed?

Comment: Does issues connected to particular day? I mean, you need to iterate through `DAYS`, for each day load `ISSUES`. What does `setIssue()` method perform?

Comment: I updated the code snippet to be a bit more friednly. The `setIssueCount` simlply sets the count and returns an instance `Snapshot`.

Comment: Updated the snippet again, it seems to work in a small unit-test with dummy values, but not on the production code.

Answer (score 0):

The updated code snippet worked well for me.